# On behalf of flow MFA - Missing WWWAuthenticate header

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, msal

I'm building this sample:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/2-web-api-now-calls-microsoft-graph/

For me this sample breaks when checking the WWWAuthenticate header:

```
if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden && response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Any())   -- Line 307 MainWindow.xaml.cs
```

It doesn't seem to deserizalize response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate correctly so this code sample:

```
AuthenticationHeaderValue bearer = response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.First(v => v.Scheme == "Bearer");
```

Brings back null.

I'm getting the following when I do a response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.ToString()

```
Bearer consentUri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/6e93a626-8aca-4dc1-9191-ce291213123//oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=0f123a63-71c2-40e2-b611-cfb813a88b&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44351/signin-oidc&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20api://34b7283b-b8c1-4279-b1d0-c381133407bd/access_as_user", claims="{"access_token":{"capolids":{"essential":true,"values":["e7bb91dc-47d0-4d45-81232-7fe86acf3c79"]}}}", scopes="api://31383b-b8c1-4279-b1d0-c381be0407bd/access_as_user", proposedAction="consent"
```

Is there an issue with the ReplyForbiddenWithWwwAuthenticateHeader method from Microsoft.Identity.Web library.